# What can I use instead of paddle attachment for a stand mixer?

Tags: stand-mixer

I only have [this machine](http://upload.tarad.com/images2/c3/9e/c39ea760217f7d2272abb1e74f096b7c.jpg).

and it has only two type of attachment not the paddle. Can I use one of these two? or I need to buy a new one that has paddle?

Comment: What are the two attachments you *do* have, and what is the application you want to perform?   Paddles are sort of the default attachment in a stand mixer for basic mixing and creaming.  Whatever the standard beater or attachment is for your mixer should perform these tasks fairly well.

Comment: I have two type in the picture like this http://www.weloveshopping.com/shop/m_paragon8822/H508.jpg 
but it is a stand mixer. I have a whipper attachment too.
It required in this recipe: http://www.japanesecooking101.com/green-tea-cookies-recipe/
I want the get the best result not compromise solution.

Comment: It depends on what you want to make, what are you trying to produce?

Comment: I want to make this recipe: japanesecooking101.com/green-tea-cookies-recipe

Comment: All the links (in the question and the comments) have gone AWOL. Is the original poster still around, or can someone else supply pictures so this question can still be useful? Currently, it's... not.

Answer (score 1):

For some brands of stand mixer, the paddle attachment is the sort of default attachment for basic mixing, and for creaming.  It does not excel at whipping egg whites, or stiff bread doughs, but these brands come with a separate whisk attachment for that purpose.

Of the two sets of beaters pictured in the image you have shared, the ones in the machine are your standard beaters.  You would use them for almost every task--they are general purpose, although perhaps not ideal for everything.  This includes mixing, creaming, and whipping egg whites or whipped cream.

The kind of corkscrew shaped ones are intended for kneading stiffer bread doughs.

Comment: alright, the general purpose can be use instead of paddle, not the best result but good enough right? thank you so much SAJ14SAJ. You always help me. you are really good person